# Power BI drilltrough to load duration curve

Tags: sorting, powerbi, drillthrough

I have the following data with time stamps

[image]

For my dashboard this data is summed for each month, producing the following chart:
[image]

Now, I want to be able to drill through on the column chart to show a duration curve of the data in the line chart as:

[image]

Comment: What is the bottom chart? What value is being plotted? A running total? What's on the x-axis?

Comment: The bottom chart is plotted with the values from the top one sorted with descending order, and the x-axis is just the rank of the values, i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.